# MySQL: Date comparsion

Tags: mysql, date

can anyone tell me, why

```
SELECT * FROM tracklist WHERE 'date' >= '2013-07-09'
```

returns data before and

```
SELECT * FROM tracklist WHERE 'date' <= '2013-07-09'
```

returns data after the given date? The corresponding MySQL column is 'date' with entries like '2009-06-05'. Why does it MySQL the other way i ask for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'date'` is a string... I think you probably meant to use backticks (`).

More generally, it's always better to explicitly convert a string to a date:

```
SELECT * FROM tracklist WHERE `date` >= DATE '2013-07-09'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tracklist WHERE `date` <= DATE '2013-07-09'
```